# (Dual monitors) Indicators displaying in panel on both monitors

Tags: unity, indicator, multiple-monitors, panel

The time, power, notification, networking and weather applets are displaying in the panel on both of my monitors in Natty. Is there a setting that I can change to ensure they only appear once within my top panel?

Comment: The same thing happened to me. It wouldn't have been as much of a problem if the indicators on my second monitor weren't cut off, either. This, and a bunch of other bugs, forced me to downgrade to Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately I think this is classed as a feature in Unity. I personally don't like it either.

You can 'affects me also' or add your opinion to launchpad bug [754337](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/754337)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/742020

Comment: That's not the same bug